# Switch Button's Label using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to switch a button's label on each click.

Following is the code I have implemented :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#details_button").click(function() {
                var button_text = $("#details_button").attr("text");
                button_text == "Hide" ? $("#details_button").text("Details") : $("#details_button").text("Hide");
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="details_button" type="button">Details</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the label in 'details_button' to change each time it is clicked, from '**Details**' to '**Hide**' and vice versa.

But it only changes once, from '**Details**' to '**Hide**', and then it does not change on later clicks.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$("#details_button").attr("text");` to `$("#details_button").text();`

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rsnSx/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/z7mrs/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/dNzrq/

API used:

`.html()` - http://api.jquery.com/html/

`.on` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
    $(document).on('click','#details_button',function() {

        var button_text = $(this).html();
        button_text == "Hide" ? $(this).text("Details") : $(this).text("Hide");;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 $("#details_button").html() == "Hide" ? $("#details_button").html("Details") : $("#details_button").html("Hide");;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#details_button").click(function(e) {
        var self = $(this); //cache object
        self.text(function () {
            var text = self.text();
            return text === 'Hide' ? 'Details' : 'Hide';
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});​​
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TDr3Q/

This could also be shortened to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#details_button").click(function(e) {
        $(this).text(function () {
            return $(this).text() === 'Hide' ? 'Details' : 'Hide';
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TDr3Q/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line :

```
var button_text = $("#details_button").attr("text");
```

to:

```
var button_text = $("#details_button").html();
```